# How to execute my operator (wikibooks.org 2020)?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I am trying to learn python for blender,
following this and many other things online.
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Advanced_Tutorials/Python_Scripting/Addon_Anatomy

I open the scripting editor, copy and paste the "complete script"
And run the script.
The script dont give me any error,
but i cant find it in the search menu operator.

What am i missing?
[image]

Comment: If you want working examples of python scripts, you can always dig into the templates (next to Format on the top of the text editor). For example the Simple operator presents a minimum working example of an operator. From there you can expand bit by bit until your own operator works.

Comment: Can you run the operator from the console, like this? bpy.ops.mesh.make_tetrahedron('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

Comment: Yes i cant find in the "Search menu" neither the template of simple operator.
I close and restart blender for not overlap the two operator registration.
No i cant run the operator with bpy.ops.mesh....

Comment: And like this? https://gist.github.com/unwave/c65e1b59b5833251ee87805bcc6e9bc4

Comment: Yes this script make return the output true to the console, so the operator is in blender.
Joonas resolved the problem, there is a checkbox to be able to find extra-script!!!

Comment: This site is no regular forum so please don't add "solved" to the title, just accept one of the answers instead... Thanks.

Comment: bpy.ops.mesh.make_tetrahedron('INVOKE_DEFAULT') should have worked regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works just as it is supposed to work. You just need to enable Operator Search to use it. You need to select Edit -> Preferences. Under Interface check Developer Extras checkbox.

[image: Developer Extras]

Now you can find Operator Search from Edit drop down menu.

[image: Operator Search]

Search Add Tetrahedron

[image: Add tetrahedron]

[image: Result]

### Errors

You can select Window -> Toggle System Console to see the errors your code gives.

[image: Toggle System Console]

Comment: hi, thanks , i got no error at all, no red flag , no console errors, i added a screenshot in my post

Comment: Hi, the line 26 already start with the # so its a comment and irrilevant , right?
i removed the whole line , just in case, but i still cant find the operator in the search...
Any suggestion on where learn this things for the new blender 2:90? 
its really hard find guides that works

Comment: @Est Silly me. I should have read the code info first before assuming too much. Sorry about that. I edited the answer and it should work as it's supposed to work.

Comment: oooooooooooooooooo thankyou
that little check!,omg.. every time so much time wasted.
thank you man, none of the guide ever said nothing about that little check.
Now i can find it in the search. Thankyou very much